# SQL command problems (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I am successfully connecting to my sql 2008 server hosted on winhost.com. But I am following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx which was suggested in an answer from: [Connecting to SQL Server Database C#-WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357374/connecting-to-sql-server-database-c-winforms) and I keep getting the exact same error when I try to:

- Insert something into the table.
- Retrieve something from the db.

The error is: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.".

I don't know what's wrong. The error message is very vague, and everything seems to look fine.

I am using all the examples from the above tutorial, but they all give the same error.

Any suggestions? Does anyone have any other tutorials/articles for me I can have a look at?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says `INSERT INTO table ...` you have to change `table` to be the actual name of your table as it says in the text just beneath:

> Now we will take a look at the values. `table` is simply the table within the database.

If you chose to call your table `table` then you can write `[table]` but it would be better to change the table name to something else.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the name of my table. I just clicked on "Create Database" on the winhost.com site and then it gave me a connection string to use. And I have no way of looking "inside" the database. Would you by any chance have some sample code to create a table?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT);` creates a table called foo with a column called bar of type INT.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your kind help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`TABLE` is a reserved word, try surrounding it with brackets, if you have created a table called table.

```
[table]
```

Answer (score 1):

Where `table` appears in that tutorial, it's meant to be a 'placeholder' for an actual table name - `table` by itself is an illegal table name - hence the syntax error.  If you need to use this name then `[table]` would be fine.